# FireFox and Chrome not showing newest cache version

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, caching

I'm working on a small project which requires HTML5 appcaching. For this small project I need a simple .gif image and the page itself to be cached. Saving the cache works fine, both browsers also show the cached version.

But when i'm releasing a new manifest file, with other .gif images on the server, FireFox and Chrome won't show the newest version of the site. This happens even when i'm clearing the browser cache. when i'm trying to do the same thing: save page in cache -> edit page -> update manifest file version -> refresh page, swap cache, in Internet Explorer, it's works perfectly and always shows the newest version of my webpage

Here is my manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-21 v1.1.50
Index.html
pic.gif

NETWORK:
*
```

And here is my method for swapping in the new appcache on the updateready event:

```
appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(event) {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
    console.log("Update ready.");
    if (confirm('Een nieuwe versie van deze pagina is beschikbaar, wilt u deze weergeven?')) {
        window.applicationCache.swapCache();
        window.location.reload();
      }
}, false);
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong, or even what the browser is doing wrong? And help me both Chrome and Firefox showing the newest cache version aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: bump! Stil haven't found a solution yet, please can someone help?
Edit 2: bump, again! Still no clue about this.

Another BUMP